# Rename roles/rolename/tasks/main.yml to rolename.yml in Ansible

Tags: ansible

By default, Ansible looks for the tasks for a role in a main.yml.  I have too many main.yml files and I'd like to rename this to rolename.yml or something that is more unique. How can I change Ansible's default behavior to use rolename.yml instead of tasks/main.yml?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Bruce already pointed out this is hardcoded. But I have an issue with this behavior as well, as my IDE displays the filename in the tab and I used to have a bazillion tabs named "main.yml".

My standard setup is to have two files:

- main.yml
- *role-name*.yml

In the *main.yml* then simply is an `include` task to the *role-name.yml*. Along with this include I handle tags, because I want all my roles to be tagged with their name.

```
---

- include: role-name.yml
  tags: role-name

...
```

Comment: Similar approach here as well - main.yml includes my 'I can actually see what I'm working on based on filename only' yaml file. Given no other code is listed in the main.yml other than the route to the better named file, apart from the initial creation they are never changed so are never confusing.

Comment: best option (short of patching Ansible) I've seen, its weird to me that this include is relative to the role directory, not the main.yml file. Do you have any tips for making ./vars/main.yml less dumb?

Comment: I used this exact same approach (I think independently invented, though maybe I read this comment and forgot), but unfortunately the tag application breaks with the new `include_tasks` approach of Ansible 2.5+.

Comment: This plugin is a workaround for the tagging issue if you want role-based tag names: https://gist.github.com/rkrzr/f5387167fa7b4869e2dca8b713879562

Comment: For defaults you can have a _folder_ called "main" and it will include all files in that folder but that doesn't seem to work for tasks unfortunately, so this looks like the best approach.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this.  The name `main.yml` is hardcoded into the ansible source code. (If you really care, look for the function `_resolve_main` in [this file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/playbook/play.py).)

Role tasks will always be in the file `roles/<rolename>/tasks/main.yml`, variables in `roles/<rolename>/vars/main.yml`, etc.  Because the path that each file lives in provides the full detail of the name of the role & purpose of the file, there's really no need to change the name from main.yml.  You would just end up with something like `roles/<rolename>/tasks/<rolename>.yml` which is redundant.

This is all documented in Ansible's [Best Practices](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_best_practices.html) document.

Comment: Why one can't end up with paths like `roles/<rolename>/tasks.yml`? IMO, it would be nice to be able to use such simplification. Are there any hidden pitfall?

Comment: "... there's really no need to change the name from main.yml ..." - you're missing the point, that many editors display only the file name on the tab. So if I have a dozen ansible files open, I have a dozen tabs _with the same name_. Sure, I can mouse over the tab to see the path, or I can have a comment at the top of each file noting the role and type, but it's far more of a pain than it needs to be.

Comment: The link no longer includes a _resolve_main (doesn't include the string "main"

Answer (score 2):

As workaround one can symlink conveniently named `rolename_tasks.yml` to `main.yml`...